# C# HttpClient -Not Found-

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

here's my issue.

I'm using HTML parsing to get the contents of a webpage and I'm downloading the html code using an HttpClient, at first everything works fine but after 4-5 queries I keep getting a 404 error, it's like I'm ip banned.

I have contacted the support of the site and they told me that this is not coming from their side.

Here's my code for this

```
    public async static Task<List<Song>> Search(string query)
    {
        List<Song> searchResults = new List<Song>();
        query = SearchEndpoint + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var resp = await client.GetAsync(query);
        string htmlSource = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

and after this I'm parsing the html source.

Any ideas on what might be happening?

Kind regards!

Comment: It is very hard to say without seeing the code you are using.

Comment: @Seany84 here's the code i'm using 

        public async static Task<List<Song>> Search(string query)
        {
            List<Song> searchResults = new List<Song>();
            query = SearchEndpoint + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query);

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var resp = await client.GetAsync(query);
            string htmlSource = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Comment: How often are you calling this? Many sites do limit how often you can do a search on their page, so you don't take up too many limits. I wouldn't put too much stock into the site's support answer, honestly.

Comment: @MikeCaron every time a user searches for a song, when I'm using it from my pc it works fine. I can search without getting "banned".

I'll try changing the user agent and some headers from the HttpClient 
to make it seem like it's coming from a pc browser.